# VBA - Attaching a worksheet to an email

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to attach a worksheet saved as a pdf as an attachment on an email.

I've managed to figure out how to save pdfs, and I know how to save worksheets as pdfs, but I want to be able to attach the pdf to the email without having a hard copy of the pdf saved down. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think you can attach a document that isn't saved (as it wouldn't have any filepath?), although I may be wrong. However, why not just save it, attach it, then programmatically delete it right after?

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to use this code I found, with a little modification you can get it working quite easily! :)

```
Private Sub GenerateEmail(TemplateFileName As String, AttachmentFilePath As String, tableRange As Range, subjectText As String, Optional AdditionalCC As String)
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   Dim OutApp As Object
   Dim OutMail As Object

   Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

   '''' This will use a pre-existing template, otherwise use commented out line below is and cut this line out
   Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(TemplateFileName)
   'Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

   With OutMail
      '.Recipients.Add AdditionalCC
      '.sendTo = sendToText
      '.CC = sendCCText
      '.BCC = sendBCCText
      '.Subject = subjectText

      '''' Use this for current Workbook (ONLY IF SAVED) ie. You'll need to create a function to save the Workbook first
      '.Attachments.Add (ActiveWorkbook.FullName)
      '''' Use this if you know the location for the saved Workbook
      .Attachments.Add (AttachmentFilePath)
      .Display
   End With

   On Error GoTo 0

   Set OutMail = Nothing
   Set OutApp = Nothing

   With Application
      .ScreenUpdating = True
      .EnableEvents = True
   End With

End Sub
```

If you'd like to review the website I acquired this from, [click here](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail1.htm)